# How to get a distinct number of IDs when they can be associated with different tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table called Messages:

```
ID | CustomerID | CarID | TruckID | CreatedByID | Date
1         23        null     null        2343    1/27/2014
2         null        56     null        2343    1/27/2014
3         null      null       78        2343    1/27/2014
```

A Message can be either associated with a Customer, Car, or Truck. A Car and Truck will also have a CustomerID, so while a specific Message may be for a Car, it is also associated with a Customer.

a) In the example above, if Car 56 and Truck 78 both belong to Customer 23, then the total Customers User 2343 helped is 1.

b) If Car 56 and Truck 78 belonged to different customers, then the total is 3.

I'm now sure how exactly to query this, I have this query but it should only give me the total for the Cars(most Messages will be for a Car).

```
(SELECT CreatedByID, count(distinct(CarID)) AS Count 
 FROM Messages 
 WHERE CarID is not null 
   AND CreatedDate >= @StartDate 
   AND CreatedDate <= @EndDate 
   AND CreatedByID IN 
       (SELECT UserID FROM @UserIDs) 
 GROUP BY CreatedByID
) TotalCustomers on TotalCustomers .CreatedByID = u.UserID
```

So in example b I should only get 1, but thats incorrect.

How can I modify this to take example b into consideration?

@UsersIDs is a temp table with just UserIDs

I tried this but I don't think it's correct(and doesn't take into consideration Trucks and I'm not sure it can). Also I have the CreatedByID hard coded and when I tried to alter the query to have a similar grouping as above I couldn't do it properly.

```
select CarID 
from Card 
where CustomerID not in (
    select CustomerID 
    from Messages 
    where CustomerID is not null 
      and CreatedByID  = 2343 
      and CreateDate >= @StartDate 
      AND CreateDate <= @EndDate 
    )
  and CarID in (
    select CarID 
    from Messages 
    where CarID is not null 
      and CreatedByID  = 2343 
      and CreateDate >= @StartDate 
      AND CreateDate <= @EndDate
    )
```

Comment: Why don't you have the customer id and carid/truckid for a given record in the same table?

Comment: Its an existing system and the request for this data happened well after it was designed, so unfortunately that is out of my hands.

Comment: Do you have car and truck (or maybe CustomerCars/CustomerTrucks) tables that both have a foreign key back to the CustomerID that you could join to in order to get the customerID for each carID/truckID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data has only one entity defined per message.  Assuming this is the case, you can do:

```
select coalesce(m.customerid, c.customerid, t.customerid) as customerid, count(*) as cnt
from Messages m left outer join
     Cars c
     on m.carid = c.carid left outer join
     Trucks t
     on m.truckid = t.truckid
group by coalesce(m.customerid, c.customerid, t.customerid);
```

You can add in a `where` clause for the additional filtering suggested by your sample code.

Note:  The `count(*)` assumes that at least one of the ids matches one of the other tables.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the count of customers helped, subtotaled by the `createdByID`, then it would be something like this:

```
SELECT  m.createdByID
    --, m.CreatedDate --if you wanted the count of customers helped by date, then un-comment this line
    , COUNT(DISTINCT COALESCE(m.CustomerID, c.CustomerID, t.CustomerID)) as CustomersHelpedCount
FROM [Messages] m 
    LEFT JOIN Cars c ON m.carID = c.carID
    LEFT JOIN Trucks t on t.truckID = m.truckID
WHERE m.CreatedDate between @StartDate and @EndDate
    AND m.createdByID in (SELECT UserID FROM @UserIDs)
GROUP BY m.createdBy
    --, m.CreatedDate --if you wanted the count of customers helped by date, then un-comment this line
```

Comment: As Gordon mentioned in his answer, this assumes that there is only one Customer tied to each Car or Truck.